# Need to modify Query Parameter before sending to API in core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, action-filter

I need to decrypt the parameters before sending them to API and this is a repetitive task so I decided to create an action filter which would take my parameters, decrypt them and then pass them to the API. I tried to implement it but things seems to fail as I am getting the exception 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Here is the code, I am new to net core, any help would be appreciated

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> parameters = context.ActionArguments;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> parameter in parameters)
        {
            context.ActionArguments[parameter.Key] = Security.Decrypt(parameter.Value.ToString());
        }


    }
```

And also how can the modified parameters be passed to the API controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `foreach` loop a collection is read-only you can't modify it.

You could copy `ActionArguments` collection before iterating through it by calling `ToList`:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> parameter in context.ActionArguments.ToList())
{
    context.ActionArguments[parameter.Key] = Security.Decrypt(parameter.Value.ToString());
}
```